# Ruby: AWS-SDK Error Installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I've recently followed [this guide](https://github.com/bvmake/WhosGotWhat/wiki/Installing-Rails-on-free-Amazon-EC2-Micro) for installing rails on my EC2 server. What I'm trying to figure out now is how do I install the [rails aws-sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsRuby/latest/DeveloperGuide/ruby-dg-setup.html#ruby-dg-setup-env) (do I even need to?).

When I run "gem install aws-sdk" I get the following error:

> gem install aws-sdk

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing aws-sdk:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

I'm not really sure what to do from here....

Comment: This error shouldnt be happening if you followed step #7. Are you sure it finished successfully?

Comment: I kind of messed up and installed rails before number #7, and then went back to install #7 (and I tried install rails command again, but it didn't really do anything)

Comment: Finish #7 and then `gem install aws-sdk` should work. Does rails not work either? I dont know why you need `aws-sdk` so I can't answer that question. You certainly dont NEED it for running Rails on EC2.

Comment: [I just uninstalled it, and reinstalling rails... ]

Comment: I'm not sure if rails works... i'm totally new at this.  I want to get to "hello world" but i'm dying here...      I'm not really sure why I need aws-sdk either...

Comment: I did that.  Uninstalled Rails.  redid #7 (said "nothing to do"), and reinstalled rails.  Still have this error:Successfully uninstalled rails-4.1.4
[root]# gem install rails
Fetching: rails-4.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-4.1.4
Parsing documentation for rails-4.1.4
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.1.4
Done installing documentation for rails after 192 seconds
1 gem installed
[root@ip-172-31-16-111 ec2-user]# rails -v
bash: rails: command not found

Comment: which ami have you used, ubuntu or something else

Comment: Ubuntu. the linux AMI one

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `aws-sdk` gem unless you are making API calls directly to AWS from your Rails application. This can be common if you want to upload files to Amazon S3, connect to Amazon DynamoDB, or send emails with Amazon Simple Email Service.

If you are going to start using the `aws-sdk`, I would strongly recommend using the version 2 SDK. It has a single dependency on a pure Ruby gem, so you would not be experiencing these gem install failures.